# How to use requestAnimationFrame inside function with arguments?

Tags: javascript, svg, requestanimationframe, svg-animate

I trying to animate much svg paths, but function not working

Error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
 function dashOffset(selector, dashStart, dashFinish, speed) {
    if (offsetStart >= offsetFinish){
        selector.style.strokeDashoffset = offsetStart;
        offsetStart -= speed;
    } else{
        return
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(dashOffset(selector, dashStart, dashFinish, speed));
}
```

with global variables it work perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You schedule a function that calls `dashOffset`, you don't call `dashOffset` itself:

```
function dashOffset(selector, dashStart, dashFinish, speed) {
  // ...
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    dashOffset(selector, dashStart, dashFinish, speed);
  });
}
```

Or with ES6 syntax,

```
function dashOffset(selector, dashStart, dashFinish, speed) {
  // ...
  requestAnimationFrame(() => dashOffset(selector, dashStart, dashFinish, speed));
}
```

Or, if your arguments will never change, you can explicitly prebind all your values:

```
function processOffset(selector, dashStart, dashFinish, speed) {
  // ...no request here...
}

// and in some other part of your code (probably inside wherever
// you have the actual argument instantiation available:
var runOffset = processOffset.bind(this, selector, dashStart, dashFinish, speed);
requestAnimationFrame(runOffset);
```

Here [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) yields a new function with it's running context ("this") as well as any number of call arguments pre-filled as it were.

However, the ES6 syntax solution is typically easiest to work with, as well as read for others.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be deferred instead of being invoked directly, e.g.

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => dashOffset(selector, dashStart, dashFinish, speed));
```